# Rational behind SAML2 destination validation on signed messages

Tags: saml-2.0

SAML Bindings spec contains the following under security considerations for Redirect and POST bindings:

> If the message is signed, **the Destination XML attribute in the root
>   SAML element of the protocol message MUST contain the URL** to which the
>   sender has instructed the user agent to deliver the message. The
>   recipient MUST then verify that the value matches the location at
>   which the message has been received.

I'm trying to understand why destination is required when the message is signed.

SAML Core says:

> This is useful to prevent malicious forwarding of requests to
>   unintended recipients, a protection that is required by some protocol
>   bindings.

I totally get it, but what's the rational behind making it a MUST when messages are *signed*?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is to make sure that nobody (attackers) can take a valid SAML message and send it to another system for which the message wasn't originally intended. SAML contains multiple checks to prevent these types of attacks (Audience element is one of them) and the mandatory check for Destination is another.

Signatures do not provide this protection on their own, signature only guarantees that the message was created by someone and that it wasn't changed since creation, but they don't include any information about for which endpoint was the message actually intended - and that's where the Destination comes in place.

The Destination checking is a "MUST" because authors of SAML thought that similar attacks are dangerous enough to warrant preemptive protection as part of the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

If the message is *not* signed, anyone can modify the response anyhow without being noticed. So there is no point in making it a MUST. Yet, when the messages *are* signed the Destination attribute cannot be changed and thus becomes of value, hence, it make sense to make it a MUST requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the input. However, I still don't understand why the request sender MUST *put* the Destination in the message.